# HTML string passed in to jQuery .append() function not displaying

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax call which returns the following HTML:

```
<form action="/Function.aspx/Add" method="post">
    <input id="Type" name="Type" type="hidden" value="Customer" />
    <input id="CustomerId" name="CustomerId" type="hidden" value="3" />


    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" style="width:7em;" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select id="CustomerAppId" multiple="multiple" name="CustomerAppId">
    <option value="BA">Option 1</option>
    <option value="AB">Option 2</option>
    <option value="DC">Option 3</option>
       </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

</form>
```

The ajax script performs great, and my result looks good in the alert() call:

```
<table id="appTable">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><label for="AppId">ID</label></th>
    <th><label for="AppName">Description</label></th>
</tr> 

<tr>

    <td>  
    <a href="/Function.aspx/Remove/221?reqId=3">Delete</a>
    </td> 

    <td>PSE</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</table>        

<a href="/Function.aspx/BlankEditorRow/3?type=Customer" id="addItem">Add another...</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {

            alert(html);
            $("#appTable").append(html);
        },
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

However, my HTML never shows up.
I tried:

- Replacing the `html` variable in the script to `'<tr><td>Hello!</td></tr>'`:  that works.
- Removing all  and  tags, leaving the plain  and contents:  that did NOT work.
- Added $(document).ready() to the beginning of the script:  No change

I've been staring at this HTML trying to figure out what it doesn't like, and I'm just not seeing it.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing a `<table>` element. That might be the problem.

Comment: Do You have $(document).ready(function() {//script here?...})

Comment: As Frederic says, the html you are trying to insert is not valid without a `table` element, hence why a plain string works but this doesn't

Comment: where is the HTML element with id=appTable?

Comment: Hehe - the table is elsewhere on the page.  I didn't think to include that, since I mentioned that adding just a plain '<tr><td>Hello!</td></tr>' works.  I'll update the question to show it, however.

Comment: @morganpdx , you should. "This is the first thing to learn about jQuery: If you want an event to work on your page, you should call it inside the $(document).ready() function" http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29

Comment: @lam Right, I'll try that.  However, how is it possible that the .append() function worked without the $(document).ready() when the value passed to append() was simplified?

Comment: Adding $(document).ready() to the beginning of the script didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @morganpdx, if I understand you correctly, you're trying to put a `<form>` element inside a `<table>` element, with the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements residing inside the form (instead of the table). To my knowledge, that can't possibly work.

Comment: That may be so; but at this point I've distilled the HTML being returned down to a simple '<tr><td></td></tr>', still with no success.  However if I paste the exact same text into the append function, like so: append('<tr><td></td></tr>'), the script DOES work.  So what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in order to properly evaluate the data from an ajax call, you need to wrap the result in a $().

So, when I changed this line:

```
$("#appTable").append(result);
```

To this:

```
$("#appTable").append($(result));
```

The row was added successfully.

Comment: The answer I posted worked for me and resolved the problem I stated above...perhaps there is a difference in the issue that you are encountering?  Reading the comments posted to the original question might provide some guidance.

Comment: You are right. I did not use append() properly. I am using after() now, and it works properly.